# Etymology "Pod" Sanskrit roots

Tags: etymology, latin, sanskrit

In sanskrit "Pad" (rhyming with mud with a soft 'd') means feet; so does pod in Latin . Do they have same roots.

Comment: Have you tried digging up the etymology yourself?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/p%E1%B9%93ds#Proto-Indo-European

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are cognate forms. Sanskrit pad-, lat. pēs, greek πώς and engl. foot all come from an indo-european word *ped-/pod- in the same meaning. Sanskrit also has a verbal root pad- "to step, to go, to sink down".

Comment: Thanks; even the prefix Paedo- (Paediatric) derives from the same roots

Comment: Pediatrics has different roots: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%E1%BF%96%CF%82#Ancient_Greek and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedo-#English

Comment: @TKR I used a doric greek example to illustrate to most narrow cognate form.

Comment: @aorists: Oh, fair enough - I hadn't been thinking of Doric.

Comment: @TKR. The "most narrow cognate forms" are in the acc. s.: Gk poda, La. pedem, Sk. pādam (with long ā < o, by Brugmann's law).